# C++ multiple definition of function when moving to another file

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm trying to refactor my C++ project moving some function from a cpp file (example.cpp) to another (utils.cpp) in order to sort the project and reuse the same functions in other sources.

example.cpp:

```
double std_dev(std::vector<double> Mean, std::vector<double> Mean2, int n,int i){
    if (n==0){
        return 0;
    } else{
        return sqrt((Mean2.at(n) - pow(Mean.at(n),2))/i);
    }
}

float mean(const float* x, uint n){
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        sum += x[i];
    return sum / n;
}
```

So, when i delete the function from example.cpp just by cutting the code and pasting to the file utils.cpp, and including the file utils.cpp in example.cpp:

```
#include "utils.cpp"


//deleted definition
```

when i compile the project, the compiler fail giving the error: multiple definition of 'mean'.... multiple definition of 'std_dev', as if somehow the compilation I performed did not delete the function definitions in the example.cpp file.

I've also tried to:

- delete the cmake-build-debug folder and reloading the project
- compile the code without the functions definition (in order to have a clean compilation) and adding it in a later moment

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#include "utils.cpp"` never include a cpp file. Instead create a `utils.h` and put declarations in that with your definitions in your `cpp` file.

Comment: This is what you're doing wrong: "including the file utils.cpp in example.cpp". Read about how to structure your code with headers, for instance in a good book.

Comment: @drescherjm: "never..." unless you know what you are doing :-)

Comment: I would just give it a different extension if I really wanted to include.

Comment: *"and including the file utils.cpp..."* **Never include a source file.** Learn about forward declarations. [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can be *declared* several times (i.e. just the function prototype), and may not be *defined* several times (i.e. with body).

This is why .h files with declarations are used and can be included anywhere, and the implementation remains in a single .cpp.

---

The same holds for global variables: `extern` declaration in a header, definition in some source file.

Comment: Given that they didn't already know this, a basic example of a header file might be a good addition.

Comment: @sweenish: you are right.